# Is there a way to view the call stack dynamically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

a general question, but the code in question is this:

have an error routine that is thrown to - handles exeptions:

```
MyObj.prototype.err = function( msg ) { ... throw(msg); }
```

so to throw,

```
if( mybad ) this.err( 'my message' );
```

would like err() to behave differently depending on whether a function is or is not in the call stack.

for example, could be

```
funcA() -> func2() -> func3() -> err()
```

versus

```
funcB() -> func3() -> err()
```

if funcA were upstream, would like to alert the user and stop; whereas if funcB, would like to write the message to console and continue.

realize other ways to solve the problem, but imho bad luck to create (and maintain) state space that can be deduced from the environment

Comment: +1 for sharing your experience: "bad luck to create (and maintain) state space that can be deduced"

Comment: [Here](http://eriwen.com/javascript/stacktrace-update/) is an interesting blog post. However, because I agree with your last sentence, this seems like a "bad luck" approach, and it'll certainly be pretty slow.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome you could do:

```
var err = function( msg ) {
  // ... 
  var error = new Error();
  var stack = error.stack;
  // Do some string manipulation with stack
  // mayThrow = 'funcB is in stack'
  if (mayThrow) {
    throw(msg); 
  }
};
```

May I point out that I consider this a **very bad practice**. I think you should catch the error in `FuncB` in stead of defining `FuncB` as a function not to throw from in `err`. It is less code and much easier to manage. So:

```
var err = function( msg ) {
  // ...
  throw(msg); 
};

var func3 = function() {
  // ...
  err('Double rainbow');
};

var funcB = function() {
  try {
    func3();
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Try to understand why this is the better solution, it is about defining responsibilities for which functionality belongs to which function. This is exactly why exception and handling is designed the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to solve, but I am pretty sure there is a better way to do it than this.

That being said, here's one way of tracing functions and checking the callstack without resorting to parsing of browser-specific stack traces:

```
var callstack = [];

function traced(name, func) {
  return function () {
    callstack.push(name);
    func.apply(this, arguments);
    callstack.pop();
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var a = traced("a", function () {
  b();
});

var b = traced("b", function () {
  c();
});

var c = traced("c", function () {
  var s = callstack.join("<br>");
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = s;
});

document.getElementById('a').onclick = a;
document.getElementById('b').onclick = b;
```

You can check it out on fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/AsrSp/